# HTML Dropdown using XML File but I want 2 columns with the Second column to be a hidden textbox for reference filter for next step

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Totally new to this.

I have got the following dropdown code working with no dramas, but I have been stuck/searching to add another column (to be hidden) to use as a reference for a table lookup with the reference (Hidden textbox) being for a filter, selected after you have chosen the correct student, for a table (I will try build) under the dropdown from which I will fill from another XML file. (The common column in both XML files will be the 'STUID' column.

The Dropdown XML is a file with DISTINCT NAMES and STUID (2 columns in total) of all students.
The Table XML has STUID and other information. (8 columns in total)

If someone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. As mentioned above, I am totally new to this and just finding snippets here and there for what I need to do on this small project.

Here is my current Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Using jQuery and XML to populate a drop-down box demo</title>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "PDC_InstrExport2.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    var select = $('#mySelect');

                    $(xml).find('tbl_PDC_InstrWEB_Export2').each(function(){
                        $(this).find('Name').each(function(){

                            //$('Name', xml).each(function(){
                                var value1 = $(this).text();

                                select.append("<option class='ddindent' value='"+ value1 +"'>"+value1+"</option>");

                            });
                        });
                        select.children(":first").text("Select PDC Student").attr("selected",true);
                    } //sucess close
                }); 
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input name="Hidden1" type="hidden" />


        <h2>Header is Here</h2>
        <img src="Monkey.jpg" alt="Logo Here" width="80" height="80"/>

        <div id="page-wrap">
        <select id="mySelect">
            <option>loading</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sample of the Dropdown XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot generated="2021-07-10T12:39:06" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
    <tbl_PDC_InstrWEB_Export2>
        <Name>ABELLANOSA, ELAINE JOY-4W</Name>
        <StuID>21-05C-158</StuID>
    </tbl_PDC_InstrWEB_Export2>


    <tbl_PDC_InstrWEB_Export2>
        <Name>ALBA, RUBY SOCORRO-4W</Name>
        <StuID>21-05C-411</StuID>
    </tbl_PDC_InstrWEB_Export2>


    <tbl_PDC_InstrWEB_Export2>
        <Name>AMODIA, FAY LORRAINE-2W</Name>
        <StuID>20-05E-1813</StuID>
    </tbl_PDC_InstrWEB_Export2>


    <tbl_PDC_InstrWEB_Export2>
        <Name>AWE, DEONA MAE-4W</Name>
        <StuID>21-05C-430</StuID>
    </tbl_PDC_InstrWEB_Export2>
</dataroot>
```

Comment: Having just formatted the code slightly for greater legibility it appears that your Javascript is  incorrect. The `$(document).ready(function(){` is never closed - ie: it is missing the final `})`

Comment: `add another column` - where? Your question is not easily understood

Comment: 1. So all my ...'(function(){' must change to (function(){)  - is that correct ?
2. Sorry all new to this. Lets say I want the STUID column to be to the right of the current listing, but I do not want anybody to be able to see the column. I want the column to still look the same as it currently is. Once I select the Student, I want the corresponding StuID to be placed into a hidden textbox that I can reference in the next step.